# Compile and link 32-bit program from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I asked this same basic question yesterday, but had not got far enough to get a clear idea of the issue. Basically, this is the error I now get when building my app:

.\Debug\HotSync.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

I assume this means that I'm compiling 64-bit object modules and then trying to link a 32-bit executable. So is this a matter of the compiler itself, or of an option given to the compiler? This project was previously a VC++ 2003 project, so has always been 32-bit.

I might mention that the only versions of cl.exe that I can find are in the amd64 and x86-amd64 subdirectories of VC\bin. I have to manually add one of these paths to the "VC++ Directories" list, but the results are the same for either.

My hosting PC is AMD running Windows 7 64-bit, but I would hope that I can still build programs that will run on XP. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A default installation of Visual Studio 2008 should have put an x86 `cl.exe` and associated compiler binaries in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\
```

on a Win7 x64 system.

If you don't have a `cl.exe` there (ie., 'above' the `amd64` or `x86_amd64` directories), then you might want to consider reinstalling Visual Studio.

*Note that the compiler in the `amd64` directory targets x64 systems and is itself built to run on x64 systems.  The compiler in the `x86_amd64` directory also targets x64 systems, but is itself an x86 binary (ie., it cross compiles to x64 from a x86 32-bit system).*

You should also have a short-cut in the Visual Studio 2008 program group (or whatever that might be called in Win7):

```
"Microsoft Visual Studio 2008" | "Visual Studio Tools" | "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt"
```

that opens a command window that initially says:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
```

And running the `cl` command there with no options should say something like:

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86

Again - if none of this is there for you, you need a reinstall.

Also, make sure that the project configurations for all of your projects involved in the build are set to Win32 and not x64.

Comment: I hope this isn't due to the fact that I've got VS 2008 "Standard" instead of "Pro", but I'm getting the impression that, since I am installing it on a 64-bit Win7 Professional system, it is not bothering to install the components for creating 32-bit apps. The setup for this product has virtually no customization options, so it's hard to tell exactly what it's doing. I'll try reinstalling it and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, but my memory doesn't go back that far these days. I apparently solved the issue since I've been using it since then.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the "problem" is that I only installed C++ since that's all that I plan on using. But for some reason the cl.exe that I need only gets installed as part of the C# installation. So go figger! Serves me right for trying to save clutter by not doing a full-full install.

Comment: That's really surprising, though anytime I install VS I install all the .NET stuff, too, so I'd never run into this.  Next time I do an install, I'll try to remember to only do C++ and see what I get (but to be honest, I'll probably forget all about this by then...).

Comment: Same problem here. x86 cl.exe was not present in VC\bin (while amd64 version present in VC\bin\amd64 and VC\bin\x86_amd64 directories). I also have only installed C++. After adding C#, x86 cl.exe has been added.